# Moderator name appears twice on deleted post

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions

I just saw a post (deleted) [Crop portion of string with PHP [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568279/crop-portion-of-string-with-php) which was deleted by [Gordon♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) but is shown as:

```
deleted by Charles, Gordon♦, Gordon♦ 1 min ago
```

How is it that one person (whether a mod or not) can vote twice on the same post?

Comment: Let me guess, he voted to delete it before being a moderator and deleted it outright once he became one yesterday?

Comment: Yup, there was 2 votes on it already. One apparently my own. I have undeleted and deleted it now, so it only says deleted by Gordon♦ now.

Comment: @Gordon [I know what you did last summer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13568279/revisions) :P

Comment: Not surprised to see this come up; I have had the same thing appear on posts I act on since veing elected!

Comment: @AndrewBarber yup agreed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

asdlkjaslkdj lkasjdlkasjdlk asjdalksj

Comment: He's gone mental.

Comment: My thoughts exactly

Comment: We have no response for that kind of language.

Comment: There is a spelling mistake in lkasjdlkasjdlk

Comment: Bouncer ball. What am I missing?

Comment: Hey that's not fair! I deleted this post myself - I just wanted something to see the "deleted by". I call "foul" on a spurious undelete by someone who I @Won't mention... http://i.stack.imgur.com/T9vug.png

Comment: @TimPost Even the mighty Google Translate doesn't know what language is that.

Comment: [undelete votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191119/152859) still causing this same bug.

Answer (score 17):

Because first delete vote by Gordon was *before* becoming a moderator. And second vote was [*after* becoming a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171547/187824). There are several cases in other Stack Exchange sites for *close votes* too.
E.g.

- [Where can I get non-standard tennis net?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1261/540)
- https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1461/540
- [Enthusiastic about learning to play chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/742/316)

Comment: @NullPointer: Read this answer again.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn damn i just read content in those link instead close div :(

Answer (score 10):

The *explanation* for this curious behavior is already explained [by hims056](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171630/23354); however, this duplication will not occur after the next build.

Comment: Ooh; sweet! The OCD part of me likes fixes like this. (So, all of me)

Comment: Is the fix for delete votes only or for close votes too?

Comment: [asdlkjaslkdj lkasjdlkasjdlk asjdalksj](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171628/moderator-name-appears-twice-on-deleted-post/171640#171640)

Comment: In all seriousness, what happens now if two or more different users with diamonds are listed in deleted/closed?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - You mean like [this one](http://chess.stackexchange.com/q/721/316)?