# When I successfully submit multiple delete votes for a single post, unnecessary commas are added to the list of delete-voters on the question page

Tags: bug, design, deleted-posts

I recently tried to delete this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732100/50776 (10K only, sorry)

While deleting, it failed, but then indicated that there was 1/4 delete votes.

Further attempts just failed, but added to the delete vote count.

Finally, it was deleted, but in the delete footer, you can see something is fishy:

[image]

What happened with this question?  Why didn't it only take one vote from me to delete?

Also, from the revision history, it seems that it was deleted with the *first* vote, but didn't want to actually show me that:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172448/user-with-magical-delete-powers

Comment: Because the system is getting fed up of you deleting things with a single unilateral vote all the time.

Comment: Well... That escalated quickly...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn [Deal with it.](http://www.deviantart.com/download/263534197/deal_with_it___rainbow_style__by_j_brony-d4cwgad.png)

Comment: The first delete was enough, did you really have to double *and* triple secret delete it?

Comment: My question is why wasn't this historically locked instead? Yes, it's off topic, but there's a few decent books in there which could be a valuable resource to future visitors to the site.

Comment: @BenBrocka Maniacally clicking delete is half the fun of deleting stuff...

Comment: @BenBrocka BOOK QUESTIONS MUST DIE!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: pick them up and add the good ones to the C# tag wiki.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Simply, no.  There's *thousands* of questions that are tagged `books`.  To give a historical lock to *every single one* would diminish the value of historical locks.  If someone wants to curate this list (hint: there's a fully curated list already on Amazon, and it's searchable!) then they are free to do so elsewhere.

Comment: @casperOne True, but the problem is that we now have going to have dead links all over the internet that decreases the usability of the site.

Comment: lol a glance at the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732100/revisions) makes me think "Wow, this casperOne guy must really have hated this question"

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I'm extremely doubtful of that premise.  SO doesn't *need* the inbound links.  Also, those sites are free to grab the content and post it themselves, as long as they provide attribution.

Comment: I've always imagined @casperOne madly slamming his fist on his left click shouting "DIE! **DIE!!**" while moderating

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That particular question doesn't look extremely valuable to me. It's basically "here's what I know. what should I read next?". Some of the recommendations are outdated and overall it doesn't have much value to folks not in the same situation. (It also only got 1600 views in 3 years.)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Nope, [no inbound links](https://www.google.gr/search?q=link%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1732100%2Fin-depth-c-sharp-book-to-read-next)...

Comment: @BenBrocka I do that with *every*.  *single*.  *flag*.

Comment: @BenBrocka: You don't think he simply remapped his `[Del]` key?

Comment: hahaha...someone is trying to reproduce the situation....

Comment: Fantastic!  We really don't need to blacklist the [books] tag after all, or even auto-close them; we just need to send an e-mail to casperOne every time one gets asked.  Problem solved!

Comment: @casperOne: Good thing you don't moderate at home anymore then.

Comment: *Trying*, @Bart? SUCCEEDING!

Comment: @Shog9 I applaud you good sir...

Comment: In regards to the [recent edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/172549/2) that modified the title, I think multiple records in the revision history is a more important bug than extra commas in the display. One can be attributed easily to a bug in the display code, while the other could be misunderstood as someone *really* hating your question. @Shog9

Comment: To be fair, I *really* do hate this question @Rachel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reproduced [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/172549/revisions).

If you submit multiple votes very quickly (either because you have an itchy delete finger, or because there's a glitch in the network somewhere that prevents the first vote from being processed before the following votes come in), then they'll all be recorded as delete votes.

Previously, this would result in a display on the page identical to the one in the post history - but [the fix that Caleb references](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172549/what-happened-with-this-delete/172551#172551) attempts to "de-dup" the list of deleters that appears on the question page itself, with comma-happy results.

Comment: I can live with being faster than your website.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is another example of side effects of the bug fix metioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172457/158468) to *[User with magical delete powers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172448/158468)*. You're on record as deleting the question three times, but the bug "fix" prevents your name from appearing more than once.

Comment: Weirdly, when I first tried to post this answer I got a message to the effect that the question had been deleted. Maybe the system really *is* getting fed up...