# How many undeletes does one have?

Tags: bug, revisions-list, undelete

DoubleAA (a mod for over a year) seems to have to vote extra times to undelete a post.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/8920/revisions

> [image]

Shouldn't it just say his name once?

Week has passed and five more have been added... this is getting out of control!

> [image]

Comment: Well, the guy's name *is* "Double AA."

Comment: The Judaism site's design is beautiful btw

Comment: I'm not sure it's the same situation @juergend.

Comment: It appears to not be clearing the list of undelete-voters when it actually gets undeleted, so it keeps appending his name to the list each time he undeletes the question again. I'm positive this has happened before and they fixed it...

Comment: As an aside should the community user be repeatedly deleting what a moderator undeletes

Comment: animuson seems to be more correct than @juergend

Comment: @Bart This appears to be a different situation as [Double AA has been a moderator for more than a year](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/election). Voting to reopen.

Comment: @juergend ping..

Comment: +1 I was waiting to the report this so I could continue undeleting a couple times to make it even more humorous

Comment: @Richard My thoughts exactly.

Comment: @DoubleAA by the way, why keep fighting Community user? You know you'll lose and it can only end in tears. ;-)

Comment: I think this sort of abusive behaviour is only going to get the community user banned. Getting into a revert war with a moderator indeed

Comment: @animuson they fixed [similar case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171628/152859) of *delete* votes. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It's possible that after one more round, I'll have 5 permanent undelete votes which will work instantly if that conniving fool ever tries deleting it again.

Comment: @RichardTingle but He's also a mod. Moreover, since he lives on the server he could just unplug us all...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Didn't work :(

Comment: @DoubleAA lol! But why that poor question is being deleted all the time???

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Can we get an updated screenshot with even more freehand exclamations?

Comment: @DoubleAA done!

Comment: Whats happened to this now? Stack exchange seems to have felt enough was enough and nuked the whole lot

Comment: @RichardTingle I think we're up to 14

Comment: @ShmuelBrin For me the linked page just 404s now (not even any delicious waffels, just a big 404). Now that I think about it possibly this may be because we're in a deleted part of the cycle and i'm <10K

Comment: @RichardTingle see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8920): "This question was removed from Mi Yodeya for reasons of moderation" - give DoubleAA some time, he'll surely undelete it again soon.

Comment: @RichardTingle Hey it takes a lot of effort to remember to click a certain button once every day or so!!! Cut me some slack!

Comment: @DoubleAA Once a day indeed! I expect second by second response times! Sleep is for the weak! Although seriously it does seem odd that the revisions page pure 404s rather than "this question has been removed for reasons of moderation" that you get with the question link itself

Comment: @DoubleAA should I make your life easier and just upvote it?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I think you should upvote it as a well-written, on topic and important question. (I am going to go pressure some SE employees to take care of this already.)

Comment: @DoubleAA there. Anna Lear [solved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194496/why-is-the-community-user-in-a-close-war-with-a-mod#comment611635_194496) the problem.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Only the symptom. The system still doesn't clear undelete votes correctly.

Comment: Lol, it finally stopped at `Post Undeleted by Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦`

Comment: @Doorknob 20 times...

Comment: @Doorknob it stopped because Anna Lear reopened the question. Nice fix, lol!

Comment: Well someone got guts to fight back with Community! `respect` for him!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators have infinite undelete votes, but that's not the case here.

The cause for deletion is automatic process that deletes [old, closed and unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/152859), process that as of June 2013 runs daily.

Now as for the increasing undelete votes, those votes don't get reset when the post is undeleted thus get "stacked", most likely a bug.

Until the bug will be fixed and delete votes will be cleared, one way to stop the endless battle and avoid insanity is to simply reopen the question thus it won't be auto deleted anymore. (Unless having 0 or negative score, but that's a different story)

Comment: I think you meant this on my other (similar) question