# Why is the Community user in a deletion war with a mod?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderation, auto-delete

[We](http://judaism.stackexchange.com) have a closed [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8920/why-isnt-the-kabbalistic-doctrine-of-sefirot-considered-shittuf-if-the-christia) with 0 sum votes (+2/-2). It got deleted by the Community user. Fine.

Then came along DoubleAA (a mod) and undeleted it. Then comes Community and deletes it a few hour later.

This cycle is currently in its 20th iteration.

Why is the Community user (a robot) fighting with a live human moderator?

Comment: [Might I suggest popcorn?](http://img.moviepilot.com/assets/tarantulaV2/embedded_images/1376320822_There_was_a_firefight__screen_rez.jpg).

Comment: Maybe this is more relevant in the site specific meta?

Comment: ...oh. Wow. That's... wow.

Comment: Is it being deleted due to flagging?  Perhaps malicious flagging or otherwise inappropriate flagging by people who want it deleted despite it's appropriateness?

Comment: Skynet. It is starting. Now.

Comment: I'm also interested in why is the moderator fighting Community ♦?

Comment: @Servy It's being deleted due to an automatic cleaning that the system does for what it identifies as old and abandoned posts. It runs daily so each time it detects that this old, abandoned post is not dead when it should be dead... it deletes it.

Comment: I might be missing something, but what's the point of undeleting a 2-year-old closed question and not reopening it?

Comment: @GraceNote What would need to happen to make it no longer get autodeleted?

Comment: @GraceNote I know that's the most common reason Community deletes posts, but I also thought that it wasn't the only reason.  Some other reason might make more sense.  I don't know of a concrete way of determining which reason applies (and I don't have 10k on Judaism to even see the question).  For example, removal of a user would cause Community to delete that users's posts.

Comment: @AnnaLear ask doubleAA. But I trust his judgment over a computers.

Comment: @Servy Community's deletions now state the reason that it culled in the post history. It is as I've stated for that post, each time.

Comment: @GraceNote Great, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: `Post Reopened by Anna Lear♦ 
occurred 2 mins ago`

    `Post Undeleted by Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Double AA♦, Anna Lear♦ 
occurred 2 mins ago`

Comment: What I find interesting is a moderator just kept undeleting it rather than asking about it on meta after Community deleted it a 2nd time on him.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think this question in question actually has come up here before. Let me search... Edit: Ah, I knew it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191119/how-many-undeletes-does-one-have Though that's about the duplicate appearance of his name.

Comment: " This cycle is currently in its 20th iteration.

Why is the Community user (a robot) fighting with a live human moderator?"  

Ask Arnold Schwarzenegger. he'll be back !

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm also a mod there and I *don't* think he kept undeleting it.  (I even asked about it in our mod chat room when I saw something like iteration #12, but then lost track of it.)  I think we're seeing two automated systems at play, somehow.

Comment: @MonicaCellio hmmmm, the suggestion here is it was a human.  If it wasn't him, then that sounds like even more of a bug than this question

Comment: @psubsee2003 well, it's been happening daily at the same time, *every single day*, but DoubleAA (like most of the rest of the folks at Mi Yodeya) isn't online one day a week.  I've asked him about it, but I really don't think all those were manual.

Comment: @MonicaCellio see my comment to the answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is working exactly as intended. This automated check is meant to clean up old closed posts that were effectively abandoned.

If the question is worth keeping around, it's worth reopening. I'm not sure why that didn't happen in this case. Judging by the comments, I suspect Double AA was expecting or waiting on some additional community discussion that just didn't happen.

I undeleted and reopened the question, and cleaned up the 2-year-old comments. If you guys think the question is worth keeping now, upvote it, answer it, or even just edit it further. If you don't, close it and let the system get it out of the way.

For reference, here are the [automatic deletion criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/155160).

Comment: I think there might be [more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194496/why-is-the-community-user-in-a-close-war-with-a-mod#comment611672_194496) going on here.

Comment: @MonicaCellio The deletions were at the same time every day (that's when the check runs), but undeletions were fairly random. It's possible that there's something fishy here, but I can't think of a single automated system we have that *undeletes* posts. I'm gonna see about finding a dev to take a closer look, though.

Comment: @Anna I was going to bring up the post for community discussion when I had a chance, and then I noticed the bug (which was reported promptly [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191119/) (see comments)). The subsequent undeletions were more for the fun of it. Honestly I thought the bug would be dealt with rather promptly and then I would resume the community discussion. I _still_ encourage y'all to fix the bug that made my name show up 19 times for one vote. (I also hereby feature-request that Community user leave posts which mods have undeleted alone, but that's for a separate meta post.)

Comment: Oh oops.  Thanks @DoubleAA; I stand corrected.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's basically this meta post and I'm inclined to reaffirm that the current behaviour is by design. If you want to save a post, save it - make it no longer look like it's been abandoned. The criteria aren't that onerous.