# Why does a question sometimes not appear among the linked questions?

Tags: support, bug, linked-questions

I have noticed several cases when a post is linked in a question (or in an answer, in a comment, in a duplicate banner) and yet it is not among linked questions (displayed in the sidebar). I do not mean immediately - I know that it sometimes takes some time. I am speaking about links which have been there for months or years and yet they are not shown.

I will list some examples below - they come mostly from the sites I visit often. (If there is some kind of SEDE magic which could help to find other such situations, I'll be glad to learn about that.)

I have these questions:

1. **Why** does this happen? (Is it only in case of old questions before linked questions in the sidebar were implemented? If age of post/comment can be a factor, when did this change? In the case of MathOverflow, can this be caused by migration process to SE network?)
2. **How** can this be corrected? (Can the linked questions be updated by some automated process. If not, what could I do when I see such situation and I think that the linked question is important enough to have higher visibility and should be shown in the sidebar.)
3. **What** can I do to prevent this. (If this is intended behavior in some situations, how can I make sure that my link will appear among linked questions?)

---

Here are some examples. I have added Internet Archive links - so that this can be checked if the situation changes.

- Mathematics question [Number of ordered pairs of coprime integers from $1$ to $N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423848/number-of-ordered-pairs-of-coprime-integers-from-1-to-n) has an answer which links to [Efficient way to compute $\sum_{i=1}^n \varphi(i) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421274/efficient-way-to-compute-sum-i-1n-varphii/422477#422477), but this question is not shown in the sidebar. (I am not sure whether it is relevant, but the link is of the form `https://math.stackexchange.com/a/422477/1778`.) The only question shown among [linked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/423848) is question 1929485, while the answer links to question 421274. The question 421274 does not have this question [among linked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/421274) either. [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423848/number-of-ordered-pairs-of-coprime-integers-from-1-to-n) and also the [link for 421247](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421274/efficient-way-to-compute-sum-i-1n-varphii). EDIT: The linked questions are displayed now. But you can see from Wayback Machine that this was not the case a few weeks ago. As explained in [the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287417/why-does-a-question-sometimes-not-appear-among-the-linked-questions#comment932634_287417), this changed after Shadow Wizard posted a link and then deleted the same comment.
- <s>Mathematics question [How to find the sum of series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{2^i}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683863/how-to-find-the-sum-of-series-sum-i-1-infty-fraci2i) has commenst linking to [Prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{i=1}^n i/2^i = 2 - (n+2)/2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512065/prove-that-for-all-n-in-mathbbn-sum-i-1n-i-2i-2-n2-2n) and [Why $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k} = 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337937/why-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-2) yet these questions are not shown [among linked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/683863). The comments link to 337937 and 512065, the questions shown in the sidebar are 30732 and 674220. 51026 has [no linked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/512065). [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683863/how-to-find-the-sum-of-series-sum-i-1-infty-fraci2i) and also [link for 51026](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512065/prove-that-for-all-n-in-mathbbn-sum-i-1n-i-2i-2-n2-2n)</s> This one can probably be explained by the fact that https links did not work before 2015 according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226467/questions-dont-link-if-the-url-uses-https/248385#248385).
- MathOverflow question [Proof assistants for mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8260/proof-assistants-for-mathematics) links to [Intro to automatic theorem proving / logical foundations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1017/intro-to-automatic-theorem-proving-logical-foundations) Yet no question is [among linked questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/linked/8260). List of [linked questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/linked/1017) of 1017 is empty, too. [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8260/proof-assistants-for-mathematics) and [also link for 1017](https://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1017/intro-to-automatic-theorem-proving-logical-foundations).
- The very first comment under MathOverflow question [Number theory textbook based on the absolute Galois group?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15068/number-theory-textbook-based-on-the-absolute-galois-group) contains links to [Galoisian sets of prime numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11747/galoisian-sets-of-prime-numbers) and ["Understanding" $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2791/understanding-mathrmgal-bar-mathbbq-mathbbq). Yet no question is shown among [linked questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/linked/15068). (And the question is not shown among linked questions in the sidebar of those two questions either.) [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15068/number-theory-textbook-based-on-the-absolute-galois-group) and also links to other questions: [11747](https://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11747/galoisian-sets-of-prime-numbers) and [2791](https://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2791/understanding-mathrmgal-bar-mathbbq-mathbbq).
- Mathoverflow question [How many dimensions I need to embed a graph?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9584/how-many-dimensions-i-need-to-embed-a-graph) was closed as a duplicate of [What is the max number of points in R^3, interconnected by generic curves?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9293/what-is-the-max-number-of-points-in-r3-interconnected-by-generic-curves). Yet neither of them shows any linked questions in the sidebar, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/linked/9584) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/linked/9293). Wayback Machine link for [the former](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9584/how-many-dimensions-i-need-to-embed-a-graph) and [the latter](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9293/what-is-the-max-number-of-points-in-r3-interconnected-by-generic-curves)

Comment: In [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423848/number-of-ordered-pairs-of-coprime-integers-from-1-to-n#comment4172041_423848) pretty sure the reason is using "raw" HTML instead of markdown to post the link. (in the answer)

Comment: [Here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8260/proof-assistants-for-mathematics) it was probably  posted too long ago, before Linked Questions even existed. I'm pretty sure that any edit to the question will cause the question to appear as Linked.

Comment: BTW, your first example is showing up on the side for me.

Comment: @Mithrandir It is showing for me, too. Either I did not see it or it was not the case when I was posting the question here. But at least you can check that it was not shown a few weeks ago, see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119130814/http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423848/number-of-ordered-pairs-of-coprime-integers-from-1-to-n) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20161010200036/http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421274/efficient-way-to-compute-sum-i-1n-varphii).

Comment: @Mithrandir it's showing because I made a test, posting the link as markdown, then deleted it.

Comment: Note that apart from the missing database reindexing bug (which is never resolved), there's [another bug that nowadays HTTP links are not indexed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313113/why-doesnt-this-linked-question-show-in-the-linked-sidebar?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment826337_323667). Previously [HTTPS is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226467/questions-dont-link-if-the-url-uses-https), and the [posted regex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280358/388243) suggests that both should work.

Comment: `note that URL in code section like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361357/what-is-the-correct-way-to-insert-images-to-stack-posts are still linked`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of those are not bugs, as far as I can see. I'll elaborate.

First of all, the Linked Questions feature was added in April 26, 2010 as announced in [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/new-linked-posts/). The feature was not retroactive, i.e. it did not go over all existing links, so any link posted before that in a question, answer, or comment, did not cause the target to be linked. (Same for closing as duplicate.)
This explains the lack of Linked Questions [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8260/proof-assistants-for-mathematics), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15068/number-theory-textbook-based-on-the-absolute-galois-group), and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9584/how-many-dimensions-i-need-to-embed-a-graph).

Second, as reported in [Questions don't link if the URL uses HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226467/questions-dont-link-if-the-url-uses-https) there was a long time bug that caused `https://` links to not be picked, and it was fixed only in February 2015, and like the original feature implementation, it did not check existing links.

As for the example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423848/number-of-ordered-pairs-of-coprime-integers-from-1-to-n) this looks like a bug indeed, I was not able to find a way to reproduce.

Comment: Sandbox is showing as linked

Comment: @Cai I know, edited. (it was a live test, since I couldn't use sandbox itself as it already got the max 50 linked questions.)

Answer (score 1):

[I asked a question like this on meta.puzzling.](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5244/why-is-this-not-showing-the-linked-question-on-the-side)

The answer was basically that it had the link as `q/number` instead of `site.stackexchange.com/q/number(/name-of-question)`.

This doesn't explain all of them, but it should certainly account for some of them.

Comment: I do not think this is the case. I will add here link to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280358) in the form `http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280358`. Based on the regex shown in that answer, I believe the question should appear in the sidebar. EDIT: If you check the sidebar now, the question "Why aren't protocol relative links recognized as linked questions?" is indeed there.

Comment: @Martin Sorry, I summarized the answer incorrectly. What if I link something like [this](/q/283949/)?

Comment: I cannot see source of your comment. How did you format the link? As `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283949/`? Or simply as `/questions/283949/` or `/q/1`? Or as `//meta.stackexchange.com/q/283949/`?

Comment: @Martin Like `/q/283949/`.

Comment: Hmm, now it's showing up. Interesting.

Comment: You are right that such link are ignored when compiling linked questions, as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120678/relative-links-are-ignored-by-linked-questions). I do not think that examples provided above are of this nature, since not many users know about this syntax.

Comment: It's possible that it's showing up now because of my comment. The software probably does not check whether the link is in backticks or not. I will randomly add `/q/287411/` [link](/q/287411/) here in comment, I guess it will not be shown.