# Should auto-protection kick in when a suspended user's answer is deleted?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, protected-questions

[What is a protected question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/162102) says:

> The system (via the Community user) will automatically protect a question that's had three answers from low-rep users deleted or [other stuff].

A [meta Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/28) was auto-protected yesterday.  Sandboxes are *designed* to accumulate lots of answers, many of which end up deleted, but our sandbox hasn't been getting a lot of activity from super-low-rep users.  Except... the last thing that happened to the question before it was protected was the deletion of an answer from a user whose rep is *temporarily* 1.  (The user was not low-rep at the time of posting.)  That auto-protection strikes me as odd.

While this situation was prompted by a suspension, users with a little rep -- enough to answer protected questions, even -- can sometimes see their rep drop because of a few downvotes.  New users' rep can be *volatile*.  The point of auto-protection is to react to *answers that wouldn't have been posted had the question already been protected*; it's saying "hey, there's a problem with bad answers here, so we're going to prevent more of the same".  That reasoning doesn't apply to answers that were posted by users whose rep *at the time* was higher.

Granted, it's a weird corner case, but should auto-protection be kicking in when the user's rep wasn't a problem at the time the answer was posted?  (I'm not proposing that we start applying rep history; that sounds expensive.  If we agree that it's a problem, there might be other solutions.)

Comment: Yes. They're suspended for a reason - that reason may include prior vandalism or destruction of content. Preventing a retaliatory deletion spree is perfectly sensible.

Comment: Question protection doesn't prevent answer deletion @Nij

Comment: @Nij protection prevents people without at least 10 local rep from answering.  Auto-protection means that that happened enough, and produced bad results (answer was deleted), that the system is guarding against more of the same.  None of that applies to an answer posted by a higher-rep user who is later suspended, so auto-protection in this case isn't achieving its goal.  Maybe it's still ok (that's why I asked), but it's not aligned with the primary intent of the feature.

Comment: That does seem less useful. I expect that it's too much work to rejig for just this issue, either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an edge-case, so... Let's have a closer look at it:

- The user in question posted *sixteen answers* to that sandbox. Out of 38 total answers. Most of them are deleted, one was flag-deleted for being overtly offensive.
- The user was suspended at least in part due to their abuse of the sandbox.
- A significant portion of the remaining answers to that question were posted by a different user. Most of them are also deleted, but since that user currently has more than the minimum amount of rep they did not contribute to the auto-protection.

Now... If this were *anything but a sandbox*, you'd be crazy for even asking this question - for any normal question, meta or otherwise, this would be a crime scene: almost no one able to answer the question effectively, two users with a history of *rampant* abuse. Protection is the least of the problems.

Because it is a sandbox, things get complicated: *the whole point* is to allow users who are struggling to use the main site a place to experiment. And *boy howdy* have these two been struggling! The fact that neither one would currently be eligible to trigger auto-protect were it *not* for the suspension is perhaps evidence that the sandbox is doing its job...

...But none of this would apply to *any other post*, so no we shouldn't change the rules for auto-protect here. Instead, we need to find a different way to handle sandbox posts.

There are a few options here:

1. Disable protection for the entire meta site that hosts such a sandbox ([CodeGolf uses this technique](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8570/community-is-being-overprotective-of-the-sandbox/8811#8811))
2. Regularly archive the sandbox and create a new one, thus resetting the criteria for auto-protection. (I do this here for the formatting sandbox, albeit in sort of a weird way)
3. Instruct users to create their own, personal sandboxes (essentially using meta itself as the sandbox). (a handy example of this is [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) questions)
4. Create a few CW answers in the sandbox and then lock it to prevent anyone from creating new ones - users must then pick an unused answer to temporarily house their idea. No answers ever get created or deleted, thus making auto-protect a non-issue. ([Math uses this technique](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts)).
5. Create some special set of rules for auto-protect that only apply to the sandbox posts. This is... probably not going to happen.

Comment: #4 sounds very clever; I'm going to suggest that to the community.  We're on our second sandbox, after the first one, with 200+ answers, became unmanagable; maybe we shouldn't have waited so long.  (BTW, I intentionally asked a discussion question, not a feature-request question.)

Comment: Re #4, does editing community-wiki posts require 100 rep on meta like it does on main?  (Do I need to spin up a sockpuppet to find out, or do you know?)

Comment: Same on meta as on main, @MonicaCellio (no suggested edits on meta, so actually quite a bit more useful). This can be adjusted on a per-site basis if need-be.