# Moderator name displayed twice in the revisions list for migrated question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, migration, revisions-list

[One of my questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/not-notified-of-new-edits-on-meta-physics-se) was migrated from MSO to meta.physics.SE yesterday. I just checked the [Revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/217476/revisions) for that question and this is how it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the moderator name is displayed twice. [A similar case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171628/moderator-name-appears-twice-on-deleted-post) was reported before, but this is not a duplicate of that one, from what I can see.

Comment: possibly related: [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191119/how-many-undeletes-does-one-have](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191119/how-many-undeletes-does-one-have)

Comment: I saw this too since it was my answer, and it didn't even register at the time.  The possibly related post shouldn't be the same issue.  That was caused by a bug that did not clear delete votes after undeletion (and has been fixed since).  The one you quote in your question is unlikely since Shog couldn't have closed this before he was a mod (he was hired in 2011 and has been a mod ever since).

Comment: @psubsee2003: I just included it to make sure this is not a closed as a duplicate of the other question. People are faast, you know. :P

Comment: Shog9 reproduced himself.

Comment: Genius.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Might be a one-time glitch, didn't find it happening in other migrated questions. Still a bug of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a little script to make migrations more convenient. There's no error-checking in it, since I'm the only one using it and I'm too lazy to add any. As a result, I occasionally fat-finger a close vote and have to add another one to fix it. I'll also occasionally do this intentionally when I want to point a duplicate question at [multiple originals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/207701/revisions).

Comment: OMFG HAX!!11one!1 :O

Comment: Your secret finally exposed... ;-)